# redirect users to some file if the did not typed index.php in url php .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

As titled I wants to show some information to users before accessing actual site and then redirect them to my site.

if they type my site url like `mysite.com` I want them to redirect them to `mysite.com/info.php` using .htaccess. and the info file show information for 3 seconds and then redirect them to my site `mysite.com`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an htaccess containing: `DirectoryIndex info.php`

And add this on your info.php:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=http://example.com/index.php">
```

Be aware not to link to http://www.mysite.com in any of your websites 'homepage' links (or heading).. that would cause a user to see the info.php again. Refer to index.php/index.html instead.

Comment: You can apply refresh to be on a different page then the current page?

Comment: I don't understand your question (sorry), the refresh has to be on the page your looking at to be working if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect with php (if request is empty). But in info.php you can use code:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url=http://www.mysite.com/?redirect">
```

After 3 seconds you can redirect to index page

In index page you must test query. If query is not empty don't redirect it again

OR you can use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Comment: in index.php 

if (empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
   header("Location: http://mysite.com/info.php");
} else {
   // Begin the site code
}

info.php
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3; url=http://www.mysite.com/?redirect">

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess  allows you to perform rewrite rules. Once you have redirected to a new page, you can't use .htaccess to do a redirection after the page has loaded.

One way would be to add JavaScript on `mysite.com/info.php` defined on the pages OnLoad() which would cause loading of `mysite.com`

Comment: My problem is how to redirect them to `info.php` through htaccess. I can handle rest of part